# Repeater unable to show textbox

Tags: c#, repeater

I have a repeater trying to get multiple data to display. 
which includes a few textboxes which will show the current setting.
take note that this acts like a 'edit info' page for multiple images at once.

i also have problem displaying the images from the database.

To make it simple :

my .cs code:

```
            DataTable ChildImageDT = myImagesBAL.GetChildImageDT(userID, childID, display);
            var userList = new List<Images>();
            foreach (DataRow row in ChildImageDT.Rows)
            {
                var child = new Images()
                {
                                   DateTaken = DateTime.Parse(row["image_taken_dt"].ToString()),
                                   PlaceTaken = row["image_taken_loc"].ToString(),
                                   DetailedInfo = row["image_info"].ToString()
                };
                userList.Add(child);
            }

            Repeater1.DataSource = userList;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
```

my .aspx code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table class="content_background">
        <tr>
            <td width= "10%">Date Taken:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Text="<%#Eval("DateTaken")%>" Visible="true" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width= "10%" bgcolor=aqua>Place Taken:</td>
            <td bgcolor=blue ><asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" Text="<%#Eval("PlaceTaken")%>" Visible=true runat="server" BackColor="White" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Fuchsia" Height=50px ></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width= "10%">Detailed Info:</td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text="<%#Eval("DetailedInfo")%>" Visible=true runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

my output as shown:

note: that the output is in the "text: " but the whole text box doesnt appear.
[image]

Comment: When is the repeater binding to the data source?

Comment: its in my .cs code. after the loop of data.

Comment: Yes, I saw that but what I'm asking is are you using this code in a page load event, a button click, etc. At what point are you calling this code?

Comment: its in page load . sry about that. its solved tho just a slight tweak. thanks =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be getting a "The server tag is not well formed." error.

Just change your Eval code to single quotes instead of a double quote e.g.

```
Text="<%# Eval("DateTaken") %>"  // It's understood as string text
```

to

```
Text='<%# Eval("DateTaken") %>' // now understood as server side code.
```

Comment: it works ! thanks you so much. 

and btw, how about images , tick box and radio button ? will it be the same ?

Comment: yup. whenever you are writing server side code into html just make it readable to compiler / server that will work always